# Correctly displaying text using the razor view engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.  I have the following piece of code in my razor view:

```
@foreach(var c in Model.ChildCategories) {
     <div>@c.Name<br></div>
}
```

It works well.  Why when I take away the innder div tags will it not work?  This is what I tried:

```
@foreach(var c in Model.ChildCategories) {
     @c.Name<br>
}
```

I am not closing the break tag because I am using the strict doc type:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

The error that I get when I want to view the view is:

```
The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

I would prefer not to have the inner div tags because I don't want unnecessary tags in  my markup.

I also have the following piece of code:

```
@if (Model.ParentCategory != null)
{
     @Model.ParentCategory.Name
}
else
{
     @:N/A
}
```

I want to display the name of the parent category, or just the plain text N/A.  Am I doing it correctly?  Is it better to have the curly brackets beneath the if or next to it like `if (...) {`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Phil Haack's  [post razor on syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

```
@foreach(var c in Model.ChildCategories) 
{
  <text>
     @c.Name<br />
  </text>
}
```

but instead of using `<br />` consider using `<p>`

```
@foreach(var c in Model.ChildCategories) 
{
  <p>
     @c.Name
  </p>
}
```

the last bit with `@:N/A` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this~

```
@foreach(var c in Model.ChildCategories) {
   <div>@{@c.Name}<br></div>
}
```